# Copying a union case but with a different value in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming, discriminated-union

In F#, I want to construct an instance (correct terminology?) of a discriminated union based on an existing instance. Example:

```
type union Currency =
    | Dollar of int
    | Euro of int

let lowPrice = Dollar 100 (* or, it could be *) let lowPrice = Euro 100
let highPrice = (* of the same union case as lowPrice but with value 200 *)
```

What code could I insert in place of the comment to create that effect?

Comment: In other words, you want a generic ability to make new values of the same union case without bothering to find what is this exact case? Seems quite natural to achieve this using Reflection (see my answer below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do

```
let highPrice =
    let n = 200
    match lowPrice with
    | Dollar _ -> Dollar n
    | Euro _ -> Euro n
```

but units of measure are probably better.

EDIT

Alternatively, maybe you want

```
type MoneyType = Dollar | Euro
type Currency = Currency of MoneyType * int
let lowPrice = Currency(Dollar, 100)
let highPrice = 
    match lowPrice with
    | Currency(kind, _) -> Currency(kind, 200)
```

Comment: Hm, so there's no cleaner way of doing it? This gets a bit cumbersome when you have a lot of union cases, but it seems that is the simplest way to go. As I said above, I should've been clear that this is not actually a currency problem, so units of measure won't work.

Comment: I think that just might be our winner! Thanks, Brian.

Answer (score 2):

I think for this sort of problem it is more appropriate to use units of measure - somthing like

```
[<Measure>] type Dollar
[<Measure>] type Euro

let lowprice = 100<Dollar>
let inline _highprice (newv:int) (oldv:int<'t>) : int<'t> = 
    LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure newv
let highprice = _highprice 200 lowprice
```

the conversion function is a little tricky  but it will do what you want

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've been more clear. This is not a measurement problem; I just used currencies as an example.

Comment: @Martin - I get that - you can actually use Measure types with many other types and it may be a good solution.  If you use a union this is going to be nasty as they are not designed for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make new union case values based on existing value of the same union case  using Reflection. In order to achieve this just add instance member `Same` to your discriminated union, which first derives specific union case from the instance `self` and then constructs a new instance by the same union case, but now populated with `newVal`:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
type Currency =
    | Dollar of int
    | Euro of int

    member self.Same newVal : Currency =
        FSharpValue.MakeUnion(fst (FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(self,
                                       typeof<Currency>)), [|newVal|])
        |> unbox
```

Now applying it to `lowPrice` value below

```
let lowPrice = Euro(100)
let highPrice = lowPrice.Same 200
```

you'll get `highPrice : Currency = Euro 200`